# What is a reasonable String equals check in Rust?

Tags: if-statement, rust

I'd like to compare 2 strings in Rust. I'm pretty sure that both "strings" are already strings, but no matter what the user enters, it always chooses the Blacklist mode!

Here is what I've tried:

```
//Imports
use std::io;

fn main() {
    //Greeting
    println!("[INFO] Welcome to Tracer!\n");
    println!("[ ?? ] Use Blacklist mode ? [Y/n]");

    //Get user input
    let users_choice = get_input();

    //Check if user wants to run in Blacklist Mode
    if users_choice == ToString::to_string("n") || users_choice == ToString::to_string("N") {
        //User wants to use Whitelist mode
        trace_network(0);
    } else {
        //User wants to use Blacklist mode
        trace_network(1);
    }
}

fn get_input() -> String {

    //Creating changeable var
    let mut user_input = String::new();

    //Read Input; On Error drop MSG
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut user_input)
        .expect("[FAIL] Failed to read line");

    println!("[INFO] Your input was: >{}<", user_input);

    return user_input;
}

fn trace_network(mode:i32) {
    println!("[INFO] Starting trace !!! {}", mode);

    //Print wich mode was choosen
    if mode == 0 {
        println!("[INFO] Whitelistmode!");
    } else {
        println!("[INFO] Blacklistmode!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `String::from("n")` to create a `String`

Comment: Also relevant: [Comparing string in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27201086/comparing-string-in-rust).

Comment: `read_line` puts the newline in the result.

Comment: @Boiethios actually, use `"n".to_string()` to create a `String` :p

Comment: @JanNilsFerner naah, I'd rather do `"n".to_owned()` :)

Comment: @ljedrz [Not anymore](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/32586). Since they are now equivalent, I would argue that `to_string` is more consistent and readable.

Comment: @JanNilsFerner Whatever, those solutions are better than `ToString::to_string`